# Strange alert view showing real time in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app with a news feed. People can favourite posts in the feed. But when someone's press the favourite button, a strange alert view showing up with a message. That message if actually for the push notification purpose. Instead of push notification, It's showing up as an Alert view. Is it an iOS bug or an issue with a Push notification service? How may I fix this?

**UPDATE**

Here's my push notification methods

```
#pragma mark - Push notification methods

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken{
    NSString *token = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet     characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:token forKey:@"device_token"]
;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    NSLog(@"content---%@", token);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Failed!!");
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"Local one");
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here, How I registered for push notifications.

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

Also I realised, This is not happening in iPhone 6 Plus(10.1.1). It's happening in iPhone SE(10.0.2).

[image]

Comment: If you made the app, I'm pretty sure you also made that dialog. Push notifications don't show as notifications when the application is running.

Comment: A whole day I checked for a mistake from my side. But I didn't find anything like that.

Comment: It's in your Application implementation since that's where the application receives notifications.

Comment: Check `didReceiveRemoteNotification` function in your `AppDelegate` class, you have definitely added an alert over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS 10 push notification these methods
I guess this method is showing alert view

```
 -(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{

 completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
 }


 -(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler{
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can search the notification name in your project,
find whether other controllers also receive the notification